# Why not in caller's catch() but the try's catch?

Tags: javascript, promise, try-catch

I have an interesting case that a `Promise.reject()` not caught in its caller's `.catch()` but in the `try{ }catch{ }`.

**callDB()** calls a pg db function to perform an `Insert`, when a run-time error (unique-key violation) raised, it goes to `.then().catch()`:

```
const callDB = (param) =>
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {
        var sql = "...myInsert($1, $2)";
        var dataValue = [param.p1, paramp2];
        db.any(sql, dataValue)
            .then
            (
                good => resolve(good),
                bad => reject(bad)
            )
            // Run-Time Err like unique-key violation caught here, returns a reject.
            .catch 
            ( dbEr => { return reject(dbEr); })
    });
}
```

**f2()**, the caller, its `callDB().catch()` not catching the `reject`, but the `try{} catch{tce}`:

```
async function f2()
{
    try
    {
        ... 
        // callDB's reject NOT caught here.
        const good2  = await callDB(param).catch((e2)=>{ return Promise.reject(e2); });  
        ...
    }
    catch(tce)
    {
        // callDB's reject caught here!
        return Promise.reject(tce); 
    }
}
```

An Azure Function calls `f2()`:

```
module.exports = async function f1(context)   
{
    try
    {
        await f2().then
        (
            good => ...
            bad => 
            {
                // Caught here as Expected!
                ...
                context.res = {status: 401, body: bad};     
            }
        )
        .catch
        (
            (e1) => 
            {
                context.res = {status: 401, body: "never reach e1"};
            }
        )
    }
    catch (etry)
    {
        context.res = {status: 401, body: "never reach etry"};
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. why the callDB's `reject` goes into **f2's** `try{} catch{}`?
2. what's the difference between `.then().catch()` and `try{} catch{}`?

Comment: When you use `await`, rejections are converted to exceptions. Just like resolving is converted to the return value.

Comment: @Barmar Good point!